# Entered text should be displayed with related opted values

Tags: php, html

color.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="padding-left:200px">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <br>
                <br>
                    <div>
                        <label style="color:orange">Enter Text: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="size" placeholder="ENTER YOUR TEXT">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                            <br>
                                <div>
                                    <label style="color:orange">Select Size: </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="size">
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                        <br>
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="control-label" style="color:orange">Font Name :</label>
                                                <select name="font" style="margin-left:14px; color:black;">
                                                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                                                    <option>Times New Roman</option>
                                                    <option>Arial</option>
                                                    <option>Verdana</option>
                                                    <option>Georgia</option>
                                                    <option>Impact</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                                <br>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <label style="color:orange">Choose Color: </label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="size">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <br>
                                                            <br>
                                                                <input type="submit" value="submit">
                                                                </form>
                                                            </body>
                                                        </html>
```

Hello every one I have a very much simply question on php, I might be downvoted for this but 
I am not getting any idea on how to do this, this is what im trying to do  I have a field in which if I enter something for example say "I love coding" and after 
 entering this in the input field and later if I select any font size ,font name and color, then that entered text should be displayed with the particular values 
 can anyone tel me how do I start this work, im not getting any idea. please it will be helpfull if someone guides me.

it should be purely in php

Answer (score 0):

You can't change html tags with php, I'm not sure but maybe you can do it with javascript

Comment: how to do it in php sir